# Open each router link as a new tab in an Electron app

Tags: electron, angular5

I am using electron with angular 5. Trying to open each router link as a new tab but I am not finding anything that could help me to achieve this. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding target="_blank" to you  tag? You could also try a click navigation function as well.

```
    <a routerlink="someUrl" target="_blank">
or
    <a routerlink="someUrl" (onClick)="navigate(someUrl)">

    public navigate(url: string):void {
       window.open(url);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It opens a new window with blank page

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: If it is opening a new window then it is working. You may need to check your url routing, could be going to a blank page or a nonexistent route?

Comment: As I said I want it as tab not a new window. Thanks for your response

Comment: I am waiting for the proper answer. It would be greatly helpful for me.